# Serial.printf() with String object of which length is 11 or more

Tags: esp32, arduino-c++

My code.

```cpp
void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()) {
    String str = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.printf("String1:%s\n", str);
    Serial.print("String2:");Serial.println(str);
    Serial.printf("char*:%s\n", str.c_str());
  }
}
```

Send `1234567890` with Serial. (length 10)

```
String1:1234567890
String2:1234567890
char*:1234567890
```

Send `12345678901` with Serial. (length 11)

```
String1:@��?
String2:12345678901
char*:12345678901
```

When I send String object from arduino(esp32) to computer with Serial.printf("%s"), if its length is 11 or more, the strange is sent.

```cpp
String str = "12345678901";
Serial.print(str); // ok
Serial.println(str); // ok
Serial.printf(str); // incorrect syntax
Serial.printf("%s", str); // error
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the length.

It's because you're passing a `String` object to the `%s` format in `Serial.printf()`.

A `String` is not a C string. The `%s` format in `printf()` is intended to work with a C string - it takes the value corresponding to it and treats it as a `char *` - a pointer to a null-terminated array of characters, which is how the language C represents strings.

`%s` does not work with `String` objects. Hence the line:

```
    Serial.printf("char*:%s\n", str.c_str());
```

*does* work because you called the `c_str()` method on the `String` object to get a pointer to its underlying C string.

When you write:

```
    Serial.printf("String1:%s\n", str);
```

your program will print the binary contents of the `str` object as if it were a C string, which it is not. You're lucky it didn't crash.

When you built the program, the compiler should have given a warning about the arguments passed to `printf()`. Reading the warnings and errors that the compiler outputs can save you some grief.

Answer (score 0):

When I was using Serial.printf("%s", var); when var is a String and was short (5 or 6 characters) it worked as expected, printing the text correctly.  But when I use a String var that is longer it shows the garbled characters, like above.

Comment: passing var.c_str() in Serial.printf("%s", var.c_str()) works for longer strings.